# Perl regular expression for the following scenario

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching, match

I am vimal, I need help on matching a pattern for the following case

I have some text like this in HTML file :

```
F&#x00FC;r Clemens, <br/>Gotthard und Hermine</p>
F&#x00FC;r Clemens, <br/>Gotthard und Hermine </s>
F&#x00FC;r Clemens, <br/>Gotthard und Hermine
</p>
```

my $string = "Gotthard und Hermine";
i want to match "Gotthard und Hermine" this and i did this with `($string)[\s]*</[a-zA-Z]+>`

But i can not match this if any tag comes in between the matching text 
eg :      `F&#x00FC;r Clemens, <br/>Gotthard <b>und</b> Hermine </s>`

I need ur help friends pls sort this out for me

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you want to match ? tell us ? is it anything from `<br/>` to `<`

Comment: I want to match "Gotthard und Hermine" even if this string has inside tags like "Gotthard <b>und</b> Hermine"     note: I will match through a variable

Comment: is it possible that gotthard is also like `<b>Gotthard</b>`

Comment: You need to explain in more detail how we can know what is allowed and what isn't. `Gotthard.*und.*Hermine` will match any string containing these three words with *anything* between them, including arbitrarily complex tag trees, but that's probably not useful.

Comment: friend i updated my question pls see

Comment: only any html tags or any unicode characters only allowed

Comment: even if you just use `($string)` you will be able to match :/

Comment: both html tag and unicode

Comment: @user3354853 Are `</p>` and `</s>` tags the only boundaries for the text you want to get? How can we distinguish them from `</b>` tag?

Comment: One thing that usually helps when the matching you want is not clear, is to show something that should *not* match that is very close to one that does match. Is there *anything* that would appear inside the string `Gotthard und Hermine` that would fail the match. For instance should `Gotthard und! Hermine` match or not match? Should `Go<b>t</b>thard und Hermine` match or not match etc?

Comment: not only </p> or </s> it may be any tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to test to see if some plain text is in an html page, then you can go the brutal route and just strip all tags using [`HTML::Strip`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML%3a%3aStrip) or some equivalent module.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::Strip;

my $hs = HTML::Strip->new();

my $clean_text = $hs->parse( q{F&#x00FC;r Clemens, <br/>Gotthard <b>und</b> Hermine </s>} );

if ($clean_text =~ /Gotthard\s+und\s+Hermine/) {
    print "found\n";
}
```

outputs:

```
found
```

Comment: Thanks Mr Miller! well Im really new to perl, so can u post any link on examples

Answer (score 0):

you probably need this :

```
(Gotthard.*und.*Hermine)
```

this will match all the html tags in between also.
eg . `Gotthard <b>und</b> Hermine`

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/wF0bH3

Now suppose you have Hermine or Gotthard inside html tags in that case you may need this regex which will also consider the end tags without including them

```
[>](.*Gotthard.*und.*Hermine.*)[<]
```

eg. `<b>Gotthard</b> <b>und</b> Hermine`

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/vM7pA5

Comment: Thanks Aelor pls see the question I updated as matching through a variable called $string

Comment: you cannot match it using $string. you just CANNOT !